# Roo module create throws exception

Tags: spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo 1.2.4
When I'm calling "module create --moduleName xxx-yyy-reg1 --topLevelPackage com.xxx.yyy.reg" command from my parent project, I got the following exception...

UndoableOperation 'org.springframework.roo.file.undo.CreateDirectory@2f178e05' threw an exception, in violation of the interface contract

Any idea what's the problem about. The parent has got another module with name : xxx-yyy-reg, wondering if this is caused by that, but when I try to use other name (like xxx-yyy-rega) it's still throwing same exception. I got it success when using xxx-try-reg. Wondering what is roo trying to say?

Thanks!
Robert

Comment: Didi you solved this?

Comment: sorry, can't remember what happened, i think i just found that I don't need to do that anymore. thanks!